# OpenCV adding logo to a region of interest

Tags: opencv

I am trying to add a logo to a bigger image but I get the following error.

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows) in Mat, file C:\opencv246\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 323
terminate called after throwing an instance of ’cv::Exception’
  what(): C:\opencv246\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp:323: error: (-215) 0 <= roi.X && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows in function Mat

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application’s support team for more information.
```

can someone please correct my code? I have been trying to fix it for three hours but still have not been able to do it.

here is my code.

```
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


int main()
{
    Mat image = imread("C:\\castle.jpg",0);
    Mat logo = imread("C:\\logo.jpg",0);

    Mat imageROI = image(cv::Rect(385,270,logo.cols,logo.rows));

    addWeighted(imageROI,1.0,logo,0.3,0.,imageROI);

    namedWindow("output",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("output",imageROI);

    waitKey(0);
    destroyAllWindows();
}
```

Comment: paste your error here, instead a link to a screenshot.

Comment: looks like your image is too small to hold the logo at the given location.
`if(385+logo.cols >= image.cols) your logo is too big and has to be resized or the image size has to be increased` and same for `logo.rows`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image probably doesn't have the right size. What are the dimensions in pixels of `image` and `logo`? If `image.cols < 385 + logo.cols` or `image.rows < 270 + logo.rows` you will not be able to overlap this logo on this image at this position.